# update @model.PropertyName using AJAX-success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Is it possibe to update a specific Property of a razorviews `@model` using `AJAX`, and do this without refreshing the whole page? And not using partialViews?

I'm having this Json:

```
  {
  "WelcomeHeader": "some header",
  "WelcomeText": "some text"
  }
```

And this Json is returned from a c#-mvc-controller-method to the view and is passed into `data` in the `success`-part of this AJAX below:

```
$('#previewBtn').click(),
$.ajax({
url: 'Home/SaveContent',
type: 'POST',
data: {
model: modelDataJson,
activeId: activeId,
contentToUpdate: $("div#" + activeId).html()
},

dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
//WHAT TO DO HERE??
},
error: function () {
alert("error");
}
});
```

Comment: Once the view renders into the browser there's no longer any notion of `@model` and properties and stuff. Those exist only on the server. In your case you have javascript running on the client browser executing an AJAX request. Inside the `success` callback all you have to access is the browser DOM. Don't think of any ASP.NET MVC, models and stuff. So to answer your question: there's absolutely no way to update any server side model properties from the client without making another request to the server.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for the answer. So one option is to make my property to render with a partialView and then with my AJAX only update that specific part? The problem is: I'm having a lot of properties in the same view, if I click on one of them, then just that one needs to be updated. If I do it with partialView, there will be a lot o partials. Do you have any ideas what I can do instead? // Thanks

Comment: Why are you talking about partials? Those notions are specific and tied to the server side ASP.NET MVC part. Once you use javascript there are no longer such notions. In your AJAX success callback all you have access to is the HTML DOM in the browser.

Comment: I know what you mean. I was just thinking of using my AJAX-post to get to a c#-controller-method that render my specific Property in a partialView. That way that property will be updated in the model